# magento, very slow loading dashboard page

Tags: php, magento-1.9

the site works well on, but dashboard page on backend works for a very long time and I can’t understand why.
when I make a login I wait more than a minute

[image]

Comment: I think it's the aggregated order data on the main dashboard... that, at least, is one area where Magento 2 is quicker. You should be migrating to M2 (or something else entirely) anyway btw, M1 is end-of-life and goes completely out of support at the end of June.